# Add column dataframe based on other dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, join

How to join two dataframe like this

```
a 1
b 2
c 2
c 5
d 3
```

I want to add column based on other dataframe conditional.

```
a io
b pk
c dea
d ak
```

So output would be like :

```
a 1 io
b 2 pk
c 2 dea
c 5 dea
d 3 ak
```

Comment: have you looked into how to merge dataframes?  There are lots of great answers on here or anywhere else you might look.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using simple `pd.merge()`,

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='inner')
```

Using `map()`,

```
import pandas as pd

data_1 = {'key':['a','b','c','c','d'],'value':[1,2,2,5,3]}
data_2 = {'key':['a','b','c','d'],'value':['io','pk','dea','ak']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_2)

dd = {k:v for k, v in zip(df_2['key'], df_2['value'])}
df_1['mapped'] = df_1['key'].map(dd)
print(df_1)
```